# send data from tableviewcontroller to detailviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a tableviewcontroller named DetailTableViewController and I need to pass data to next tableviewcontroller named DetailTableViewController. But I need to pass the data as the user clicks the cell of DetailTableViewController. Then, I got error as "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".Please help me sort out in Swift 3.

Comment: try printing your passedvalue variable just before your error line once .

Comment: its nil @ Tushar Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a variable in your detail view controller to hold the value which you send from first view controller. then assign the value inside the `didSelectRowAt` method in first view controller and then navigate programatically. in this way, you do not need to implement `prepare for segue` method to send the data.

you just need to implement the `didselectrowat`, method.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selected = firstArray[indexPath.row]
        let detailvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailTableViewController") as! DetailTableViewController

        detailvc.type = selected
        self.present(detailvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**I created a video tutorial for you from scratch. [how to pass data from one table view controller to another](https://youtu.be/cxd_jo1e708). hope this will help to you.**

Comment: @Tamannah video is still uploading . please try in while .... thank you.

Comment: Please sir, can you give the solutions with reference else you can edit on the codes above too. It displays only the data from the medical array while pressing all the cells. @ Anuradh S

Comment: try the video tutorial after few minutes(still uploading) which I created for you. It will show you how to pass the data between view controllers and , how to show data with conditions. try it and let me know .....

Comment: I am waiting till now... but it says video is unavailabe @ Anuradh S

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, **never** get data from the view (the cell) in such a case, get it always from the model (data source array).
- Second of all, the signature of `prepare(for segue` is wrong for Swift 3.

In `didSelectRowAt` pass the indexPath rather than `self`, you can also delete `valueToPass`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Cell", sender: indexPath)
}
```

In `prepareForSegue` get the data from the model and pass it to the detail view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Cell" {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! GuidesDetailsTableViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        viewController.passedValue = guides[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited now but it displays only the data from the medical array while pressing all the cells. Why doesn't it read the passedValue ? @ vadian

Comment: I have edited from your solution now... how can I solve now ?

Comment: You should reload the tableView in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Still, it displays only the contents of medical when every cells are pressed. @  vadian

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the var valueToPass don't have a value when you call the performSegue. Try to assign the value of valueToPass with the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    valueToPass = guides[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Cell", sender: self)
}
```

And create your segue form your viewController, maybe you create the segue from the cell.

[image]

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the function prepareForSegue and check that the var valueToPass has a value. The crash is because something var is nil

Comment: Yes, its nil @ DiegoQ

Comment: Check if didSelectRowAt is calling before than prepareForSegue

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `didSelectRow` you're setting a new **`indexPath`**. Removing it should do the trick.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Don't reassign indexPath
    // let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Cell", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: I have given above as Error. Please have a look.